# Extraction from Numpy Meshgrids

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This should be a relatively simple answer:

I have used a meshgrid

`x,y,z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,11),np.linspace(-5,5,11),np.linspace(-5,5,11))`

to create `u,v,w`. This is actually a very complex mathematical function, but it is analogous to a simple one, say `np.sin(x*y*z)`...

Now I am interested in the length of each of these resultant vectors, so I create `norm = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`.

Now what I want to do is to split `norm` into segments perpendicular to the z-axis. Essentially so that I can get and x,y plane and a value of norm for each of those x,y points. Unfortuantely, I can't seem to figure out how to segment norm so that this is possible. How do I get each size of the norm array?

Comment: It is very unclear what your question is about. Initially you have a matrix of 3d coordinates. Then you calculate a single number for every coordinate - `sin` or `norm`. Numbers are just numbers - they don't have x, y, z components. So what are the vectors? The only vectors I can think of are position vectors corresponding to the initial coordinates. You know everything about them.

Comment: @Poolka. You are correct, I have created a single array (let's call it ```norm(x,y,z)```), which is composed exclusively of numbers. The issue is that it is a 3d array, mapping an x,y,z position to a number. What I need to do is slice that array into 2d arrays which have a constant z value. Then I will animate them by changing the z level and visualizing how to 2d array changes.